# Trouble With Dictionary Comprehension

Tags: python

I am trying to wite a dictionary comprehension that takes a list of strings and creates a dictionary from those elements. The code below contains the expected and actual outputs as well as the comprehension I am using. Any help would be appreciated.

```
s = ['Kennedy D MA -1 -1 1 1', 'Snowe R ME 1 1 1 1']

strlist = list(x.split() for x in s)

print({ strlist[x][0]:[int(strlist[x][y])] for x in range(len(strlist))  for y in range(3, len(strlist[0])) })


'''
   EXPECTED: {'Snowe': [1, 1, 1, 1], 'Kennedy': [-1, -1, 1, 1]} 

   ACTUAL: {'Snowe':[1] , 'Kennedy':[1]}
'''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest:

```
{s[0]:s[3:] for s in strlist}
```

no messing with indices...!-)

Comment: Wow! It works but I'm not quite sure how. Can you explain the s[3:] syntax? Does this just iterate from 3 until end?

Comment: I also need the 1 and -1 as integer values int(s[3:]) doesn't work. Is there any way to say convert these values to integers as I add them to the list?

Comment: @drunkenmonkey44 sure, use `[int(x) for x in s[3:]` in lieu of just `s[3:]`!

Comment: Thank you very much Alex! +3 so far haha

Answer (score 1):

Tried this

`dict((x.split()[0],x.split()[3:]) for x in s)`

Which you can modify further to:

`{x[0]:x[3:] for x in [y.split() for y in s]}`

If you don't mind having readability issues you can have

`{x[0]:[int(i) for i in x[3:]] for x in [y.split() for y in s]}`

to convert the numbers to `int`s

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a dict comprehension in this case, you're creating a list of one element `[int(strlist[x][y])]`. In python3:

```py
strings = ['Kennedy D MA -1 -1 1 1', 'Snowe R ME 1 1 1 1']

result = {}
for line in strings:
    name, __, __, *rest = line.split()
    result[name] = list(rest)
```